# What is the difference between the create and perform_create methods in Django rest-auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-auth

I'm using the Django [`rest-auth`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) package. I have a class that extends `rest-auth`'s `RegisterView`, and which contains two methods, `create` and `perform_create`. What is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: I think you got your answer

Comment: Thanks. For more information you can see the tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekhUhignYTU&index=7&list=PL1WVjBsN-_NJ4urkLt7iVDocVu_ZQgVzF

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`perform_create` is called within the `create` method to call the serializer for creation once it's known the serialization is valid. Specifically, `serializer.save()`

Code from the source - when in doubt check it:

```
class CreateModelMixin(object):
    """
    Create a model instance.
    """
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def get_success_headers(self, data):
        try:
            return {'Location': str(data[api_settings.URL_FIELD_NAME])}
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            return {}
```

Comment: Apposite username