# Post is working in model view set, with functions name post

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets

```
class Product_List(viewsets.ModelViewSet):          # >>> List of products & add product to cart
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ] 

    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductListSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  # <<< post is working 
        items = get_object_or_404(Item, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        if items.discount_price < items.price:
            ncart = CartItem.objects.create(user=request.user, product=items)
            ncart.total = ncart.quantity * items.discount_price
            ncart.save()
        else:
            ncart = CartItem.objects.create(user=request.user, product=items)
            ncart.total = ncart.quantity * items.price
            ncart.save()
        data = json.dumps(ncart, default=str, indent=1)
        return Response({'msg': 'Product Added to Cart Successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Actually I tried post with model-view-set with function perform create but its not working, so I just changed name performcreate > post. this is working any one let me know how it is possible,
model viewset allows
ModelViewSet
get_queryset
(list
retrieve
create
perform_create
update
perform_update
destroy)this method right , then why?

Comment: Please check this. Hope it will help 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53319315/7456750

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct just rename your post method with create mentioned below

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  # <<< post is working